# PuTTY authentication equivalent on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, svn, authentication, private-data

On my Windows development machine, I use Pageant with a secret key to authenticate with an SVN server.

I want to know: What's the equivalent Mac process for doing this? Pageant isn't ported, how do I authenticate?

Comment: If you want to import a key from your Windows machine with PuttyGen, then use Export -> OpenSSH to create a file in the correct format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [SSH Keychain](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/) on my Mac to manage my ssh key agent and attached keys. It runs ssh-agent, and ssh-add to manage the keys behind the scenes, but starts up when I login, stores the passphrase in OSX login keychain (you don't have to do this, though).

Comment: Note that OSX 10.5+ has ssh-agent built-in, so no additional software install is needed (the first time I accessed the encrypted private key in OSX 10.6 I was asked for passphrase; this was then "by magic" added to keychain and no more prompts since then)

Comment: blech, that link no longer leads anywhere useful :(

Comment: this is the correct link - http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Pageant is a Windows workaround for not having OpenSSH installed. Since modern macs [are UNIX](http://www.opengroup.org/comm/press/19-2-nov07.htm), you don't have to install anything!

Here's [a quick rundown on how to set it up](http://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/)

Comment: Modern Macs *are* Unix ;). http://www.opengroup.org/comm/press/19-2-nov07.htm

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3581.htm also http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/

Comment: Dead link. This is why we’re insist that you should always copy pertinent info to your answer from the linked page in addition to linking to the page.

Answer (score 4):

ssh-add and ssh-agent are the equivalent tools, which are built in. Best way is to read any tutorial for linux or os x in setting up auth with ssh, it will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

For me `~/.ssh/config` file works best. Add to it groups of configs using this scheme:

```
host shortname
user my_username
hostname host.of.the.server.example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.openssh
```

and then

```
ssh shortname
```

will connect using that settings, including the key. This lets you have lots of different keys for different hosts without having to add them all to `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

This page https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/using-ssh-agent-forwarding has all details that worked for me. Especially,

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain YOUR-KEY
```